# PyArrow read_table filter null values

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I'm pretty new to using pyArrow and I'm trying to read a Parquet file but filtering the data I'm loading.
I have an end_time column, and when I try to filter based on some date it's working just fine and I can filter to get only the rows which match my date.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from datetime import datetime
last_updated_at =  datetime(2021,3,5,21,0,23)
table_ad_sets_ongoing = pq.read_table('export/facebook.parquet', filters = [('end_time', '>', last_updated_at)]) 
print(table_ad_sets_ongoing.num_rows)
```

But I also have sometimes a null value in this end_time field.
So I tried filtering this way

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from datetime import datetime
table_ad_sets_ongoing = pq.read_table('export/facebook.parquet', filters = [('end_time', '=', None)]) 
print(table_ad_sets_ongoing.num_rows)
```

But the result is always 0 even if I actually have some rows with this null value.
After some digging I suspect that this has to do with a null_selection_behavior which is by default at 'drop' value and so it skips null values.https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.filter.html#pyarrow.compute.filter
I guess I should add this parameter to 'emit_null' but I can't find a way to do it.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I finally found out the answer to my question.
Answer come from arrow github (stupid from my side not to have a look at it earlier). https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/9160

To filter a null field we have to use it this way :

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from datetime import datetime
table_ad_sets_ongoing = pq.read_table('export/facebook.parquet', filters=~ds.field("end_time").is_valid())
print(table_ad_sets_ongoing.num_rows)
```

Comment: Edit : After upgrading to Pyarrow 4.0 it seems that filtering directly when reading the file isn't possible anymore. After some digging we now need to apply the filters in 2 times: first load the file in a dataset and then apply the filters.  my_dataset = ds.dataset('myparquetFile.parquet')
   table = my_dataset.to_table(filter=~ds.field('data').is_valid()) Note also that there is a new is_null() filter which can be applied instead of is_valid()